# es6 method of updating sub-objects of an existing parent object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I feel like there is a way to simplify the updating of certain nested objects within a parent object with ES6, but I can't quite verbalize it or track down the syntax.

I currently have this:

```
entryData = {
  exchangeData: {...}
  scenes: {...},
  takeover: {...},
}
```

I periodically am polling an API to update just the `scenes` and `takeover` sub-objects:

```
APP.api.getEntryContent().then((data) => {
  //data = { scenes: {...}, takeover: {...}
  entryData.scenes = data.scenes;
  entryData.takeover = data.takeover;
});
```

but I feel like there's a one liner which just says something like `entryData = {...data}` - but when I do this, it erases the `exchangeData` object. How do I just update the data returned from the API?

Comment: `entryData = {entryData.exchangeData, ...data}`

Comment: check your console see if there are any errors.

Comment: @Luis: That's not ES6 though ;)

Comment: Sorry - shouldn't have said it needs to be ES6 - just looking to do this in a more efficient way. I think @amrender singh's answer works

Comment: @mheavers Please mark answer as accepted if it helped you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Object.assign()` .

```js
var entry = {
  exchangeData: {"ab":1},
  scenes: {"a":1,"b":2},
  takeover: {"a":1,"b":1}
};
var data = {
  scenes: {"a":2,"b":5},
  takeover: {"a":2,"b":6}
};
entry = Object.assign(entry,data);
console.log(entry);
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried that, just forgot the `entry =` part

Comment: @mheavers You don't need to reassign `entry`. `Object.assign` mutates the first argument.